# No wireless interface detected in Linux

Tags: wifi, backtrack, interface

I'm using Backtrack5R3 via bootable CD
and getting `no wireless interface found` output.
These are the o/p of commands by which you can get details of my problem.
My laptop model is Lenovo b490(20205).

```
root@bt:~# iwconfig
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@bt:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:8d:ef:29  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15785 (15.7 KB)  TX bytes:15785 (15.7 KB)

root@bt:~# airmon-ng


Interface   Chipset     Driver


    root@bt:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)

root@bt:~# lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Broadcom Corporation
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0500000-f0507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 3c:97:0e:8d:ef:29
       size: 10MB/s
       capacity: 1GB/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10MB/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: You need the bcm43142 driver (found via Google *broadcom 4365*, which comes from your `lspci`). Not sure exactly how to do that on your distro though... Just leaving a pointer here.

Comment: I have downloaded the required driver --> wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb     but i dont know the commands to install this driver. please guide.

Comment: It's probably just `dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb`, assuming you have the dependencies installed. If not, it'll complain, and you can use aptitude/apt-get/etc. to install them. Make sure to have the kernel-headers package installed for your kernel as well.

Comment: root@bt:~# dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb gives o/p ->
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
then i googled and got this file
root@bt:~# dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu4_all.deb
(Reading database ... 267024 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace dkms 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu4 (using dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu4_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dkms ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu4) ...

Processing triggers for man-db ...
root@bt:~# what's now?

Comment: Sounds like you need to find an i386 version of the driver (instead of amd64).

Comment: yes, i just tried i386 version and got this o/p dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms:
 wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms depends on dkms; however:
  Package dkms is not installed.
 wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms depends on linux-headers-generic | linux-headers; however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not installed.
  Package linux-headers is not installed.

Comment: Looks like you already installed dkms, you'll need to install the others as well.

Comment: sir r u sure that dkms is installed, because the o/p says "however: Package dkms is not installed". and the others 2 are linux-headers-genric and Package linux-headers,right?

Comment: One of you're previous comments it looks like you installed dkms. You want the linux-headers that corresponds to the linux-kernel package you have.

Comment: is there any file for linux-headers which i have to download first or it can be done via only command?

Comment: Do you have an apt-get or aptitude on this distro? If so, those tools will let you install the packages easily.

Comment: i believe backtrack supports apt-get command. are my steps right to install linux-headers? apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: The upgrade and dist-upgrade commands are for upgrading already installed packages so you probably don't want them. The update command you want (it downloads the list of available packages). The install command looks good too. You may also need `apt-get install dkms` if you don't already have it installed.

Comment: sir, it needs an internet connection to for headers, i dont have connection other than WiFi and backtrack is not supporting it. there is got to be some offline mathod?

Comment: You can copy the deb files over like you did the other one. Not sure where the appropriate files are to download, though. Quick check of their website didn't find them. You could use apt-offline if that's already installed. Or an Ethernet if possible, since it sees your wired Ethernet card.

Comment: @derobert sir,i followed this link for installing driver

http://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560 there are 2 drivers for BCM43142/4365 steps i followed

1.installing linux-headers and dkms
2.installing wifi driver

Comment: commands o/p are --> root@kali:~# dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb gives error "dependency problems prevent configuration of wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms"
and
and root@kali:~# dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb gives error "Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.12-kali1-amd64 (x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/wireless-bcm43142/6.20.55.19/build/make.log for more information." did i miss something?

Comment: You'd have to check to see what's in that error log to see why the build failed. Is Backtrack Linux based on Ubuntu 11.10? No idea... As to the other one, it should tell you what the missing dependency is. You'd need to install that as well (or use Ethernet and let apt-get do it for you).

Comment: now i'm using kali.above o/p were from kali linux 1.0.6 which is only 5 months old. so you can guess that it must be based upon a recent version of ubuntu.

Comment: and please consider looking at log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7rtePQrvo3vWllVT25MVzhyM2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 11.10 is an old version of Ubuntu. The current one is 13.10, with 14.04 about to come out. The most recent LTS is 12.04, I believe. Also, Kali is based on Debian (not Ubuntu).  .... anyway, I suggest trying these drivers: http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/non-free/b/broadcom-sta/ You probably need the "common" and "dkms" packages.

Comment: i just realised it is based on debian. i found this post http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=109498 explaining that its      also the matter of installed kernel (3.12.6-2kali1).this kernel doesn't support WiFi even after installing the driver.now i'll try to downgrade/upgrade to compatible kernel version.

Comment: Is this still an open issue, or did you get it working?